# Magento2 SOAP Sorting error

Tags: api, sorting, magento, soap, magento2

I'm trying to use soap API. Answer contains : The sort order has to be specified as %1 for ascending order or %2 for descending order. What i'm doing wrong? request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="http://xxx/Magento-2-0-2-0-ce/soap/default?services=salesOrderRepositoryV1">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <def:salesOrderRepositoryV1GetListRequest>
         <searchCriteria>
            <filterGroups>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <item>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <filters>
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <item>
                        <field>*</field>
                        <value>*</value>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <conditionType>?</conditionType>
                     </item>
                  </filters>
               </item>
            </filterGroups>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sortOrders>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <item>
                  <field>Name</field>
                  <direction>%1</direction>
               </item>
            </sortOrders>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pageSize>10</pageSize><currentPage>0</currentPage>
            <!--Optional:-->

         </searchCriteria>
      </def:salesOrderRepositoryV1GetListRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

response:
    
       
          
             
                env:Sender
             
             
                The sort order has to be specified as %1 for ascending order or %2 for descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error i had removed this filter

```
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <item>
            <field>*</field>
            <value>*</value>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <conditionType>?</conditionType>
         </item>
```